# Transforming a Spark Dataframe Column into a Dataframe with just one line (ArrayType)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that contains a column with complex objects in it:

```
+--------+
|col1    |
+--------+
|object1 |
|object2 | 
|object3 |    
+--------+
```

The schema of this object is pretty complex, something that looks like:

```
root:struct
    field1:string
    field2:decimal(38,18)
    object1:struct
        field3:string
        object2:struct
            field4:string
            field5:decimal(38,18)
```

What is the best way to group everything and transform it into an array?

eg:

```
+-----------------------------+
|col1                         |
+-----------------------------+
| [object1, object2, object3] |    
+-----------------------------+
```

I tried to generate an array from a column then create a dataframe from it:

```
final case class A(b: Array[Any])

val c = df.select("col1").collect().map(_(0)).toArray

df.sparkSession.createDataset(Seq(A(b = c)))
```

However, Spark doesn't like my `Array[Any]` trick:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Any
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to group everything and transform it into an array?

There is not even a good way to do it. Please remember that Spark cannot distribute individual rows. The result will be:

- Processed sequentially.
- Possibly to large to be stored in memory.

Other than the above you can just `collect_list`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, collect_list}

df.select(collect_list(col("col1"))
```

Comment: Cool, it worked! I know that is not a good practice, but this is a result of a filter (really small dataframe). I was looking `collect_list ` but, for some reason, I was thinking that a `groupby` was needed to work, I don't know why.

Comment: You could also `df.groupBy().agg(collect_list(col("col1"))` or even `df.agg(collect_list(col("col1"))`

Answer (score 1):

Spark uses encoders for datatypes, this is the reason `Any` doesn't work.

If the schema of the complex object is fixed, you can define a `case class` with that schema and do the following,

```
case class C(... object1: A, object2: B ...)

val df = ???

val mappedDF = df.as[C] // this will map each complex object to case class
```

Next, you can use a `UDF` to change each `C` object to `Seq(...)` on row level. It'll look something like,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{UserDefinedFunction => UDF}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

 def convert: UDF =
    udf((complexObj: C) => Seq(complexObj.object1,complexObj.object2,complexObj.object3))
```

To use this `UDF`,

```
mappedDF.withColumn("resultColumn", convert(col("col1")))
```

Note: Since not much info was provided about the schema, I've used generics like A and B. You will have to define all of these.

Comment: +1 because this is a valid answer too. I'm not using it because I want to avoid to write the entire schema of my object.